# How many types of SQL subqueries are there?

Tags: sql, select, subquery, common-table-expression

In an effort to understand what types of subqueries can be correlated I wrote the SQL query shown below. It shows all types of subqueries I can think of a SQL `select` statement can include.

Though the example shown below runs in Oracle 12c, I would prefer to keep this question database agnostic. In the example below I included all 7 types of subqueries I can think of:

```
with 
  daily_login as ( -- 1. Independent CTE [XN]
    select user_id, trunc(login_time) as day, count(*) from shopper_login
      group by user_id, trunc(login_time)
  ),
  frequent_user as ( -- 2. Dependent CTE [XN]
    select user_id, count(*) as days from daily_login group by user_id
    having count(*) >= 2
  ),
  referrer (frequent_id, id, rid, ref_level) as ( -- 3. Recursive CTE [XN]
    select fu.user_id, s.id, s.ref_id, 1 from frequent_user fu 
      join shopper s on fu.user_id = s.id
    union all
    select r.frequent_id, s.id, s.ref_id, r.ref_level + 1 from referrer r
      join shopper s on s.id = r.rid
  )
select s.id, s.name, r.id as original_referrer,
    ( -- 4. Scalar Subquery [CN]
    select max(login_time) from shopper_login l 
      where l.user_id = s.id and l.success = 1
    ) as last_login,
    m.first_login
  from shopper s
  join referrer r on r.frequent_id = s.id
  join ( -- 5. Table Expression / Inline View / Derived Table [XN]
    select user_id, min(login_time) first_login from shopper_login
      where success = 1 group by user_id
  ) m on m.user_id = s.id
  where r.rid is null
    and s.id not in ( -- 6. Traditional Subquery [CN]
      select user_id from persona
        where description = 'Fashionista'
          and id in ( -- 7. Nested subquery [CN]
            select user_id from users where region = 'NORTH')
    );
```

Legend:

```
[C]: Can be correlated
[X]: Cannot be corretaled
[N]: Can include nested subqueries
```

My questions are:

- Did I get all possible types? Are there alternative names for these types of subqueries?
- Am I correct thinking that only Scalar (#4), Traditional (#6), and Nested (#7) subqueries can be correlated?
- Am I correct thinking Table Expressions and CTEs (#1, #2, and #3) cannot be correlated? (however, they can include Nested subqueries that can be correlated)

Comment: I don't consider CTEs or derived tables to be "sub-queries". I would only distinguish between scalar subqueries (#4), sub-queries (#6) and co-related subqueries (not in your list)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was wondering about that. Do you have any reference I could read about?

Comment: And an independent CTE that has a correlated scalar subquery in an `IN` clause?

Comment: OK, so so far I've missed: 1) Nested subqueries in multiple levels. 2) Correlated vs non-correlated subqueries combination.

Answer (score 1):

Correlated subquery:

```
FROM shopper s
...
AND EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM otherTable t
            WHERE t.id = s.id)
```

Comment: So, this one is different from #6, since #6 is a "non-correlated" subquery, and this one is?

Comment: @TheImpaler Yep. Actually I think your #6 might be slightly misnamed too.  With a nested subquery, I'd expect there to be another subquery inside that one.  But it's really tough to formulate a list like this.  There are usually multiple names for each, and it can be hard to fully separate them too.  For instance, your scalar subquery is also correlated.  All in all I think this is a cool question that will be difficult to answer concretely.  PS. I'd hate to run into your query at work.

Comment: Got you. :D Thanks

Comment: @AaronDietz . . . In the question, #4 is a correlated subquery.  The OP is missing an example of a non-correlated subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mentioned that the scalar subquery (#4) is also correlated in my comment above, but since scalar subqueries don't require correlation I think the distinction is useful to OP's question.  #6 is a non-correlated subquery.